# Установка драйвера radeon в PureOs (debian)

Tags: linux, debian, драйвер, gnu, radeon

Когда устанавливаю любой свободный(GNU + остутсвие репозитория non-free) debian-дист, при загрузке всё останавливается на проверке дисков, но до этого вылетает ошибка видеодрайвера. На форумах читал, что это из-за отсутствия radeon drm-прошивок. Знаю, что есть специальных пакет для этого, но проблема, что в консоль не входит и в GUI тоже. В рекавери моде написано, что root заблокирован. Видеокарта HD6570(ddr3, 1gb). Как установить пакет с drm прошивками? (встроенное ядро тоже radeon). Систему переустанавливать можно.

Comment: Обычный свежий или lts бубен пробовал?

Comment: Какой, какой бубен? (Мало просто пока в линуксе разбираюсь)

Comment: (какой танец плясать?)

Comment: Такой: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xubuntu

Comment: Требуется наиболее GNU

Comment: А чем обусловлен такой выбор?

Comment: Стремление к полной этичности

Comment: Ну ок. Тогда пробуешь убунту с nonfree дровами и если всё едет - уже наверное надо писать самим разрабам дистра\ядра. Потому что тут вряд ли сидят мейнтейнеры с kernel.org.

Comment: убунта работает, там много не этичных пакетов, пойду напишу на форум дебиана наверно

Comment: Ну вот значит в целом да, пашет. Тут скорее тока в списки рассылки стучаться.